# Laravel route model binding and fallback

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am working on an api with laravel. For this, I wanna return a json response for all 404 errors. I created this fallback route and placed it at the end of the `api.php`:

```php
Route::fallback(function(){
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found.'], 404);
})->name('api.fallback.404');
```

When I now enter an invalid url like `/xyz` I get the json response as expected.

But when I use route model binding:

```php
Route::get('/projects/{project}', function (\App\Models\Project $project) {
    return $project->toArray();
});
```

and try to get a non existing project (for example `/projects/9999`), then I get the standard laravel 404 HTML response and not my json one.

How to fix this?

Comment: make sure you are sending `Accept: application/json` in your headers

Comment: check this [document](https://laravel-news.com/404-responses-laravel-api), there is section called "Customizing ModelNotFoundException Responses)

Comment: You where both right. After adding `Accept: application/json` I got a json error message (but with full error stack), and after following the documentation @Webinion mentioned AND adding `Content-Type: application/json` it worked.